# .Net AssemblyInfo Delphi-Prism

Tags: .net, delphi-prism, assemblyinfo

What for is the

```
implementation
end.
```

part of the AssemblyInfo.pas file in DelphiPrism projects?
I know that between 'implementation' and 'end' there should be an implementation of a method, but what would I implement in the AssemblyInfo.pas file?

In C#, in the AssemblyInfo.cs file, there isn't anything like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unit/inteface/implementation/end are the required parts of a Delphi Prism files. For AssemblyInfo they can just be kept empty.

Comment: Is this from always or just in some newer versions of Delphi Prism?